# Printing different keys that have same value in one row from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Here's a sample dictionary.

```
example = {'a': 10, 'b': 12, 'c': 10, 'd': 12}
```

I want to print them like below.

```
12 b, d
10 a, c
```

Comment: [Python reverse / invert a mapping](//stackoverflow.com/q/483666)

Comment: Your dictionary syntax is wrong: It should be example = {'a' : 10, 'b' : 12, 'c' : 10, 'd' : 12}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks for the dupe target. I'm closing it with that.

Comment: It never ends. This is NOT A DUPLICATE.  The OP likely wants the data printed in that format, not to be able to simply perform an operation that would lead to it. There are a million "duplicates" like this a day. It's nothing short of ridiculous and it needs to stop. It's like you all look for any way for a question to be considered a duplicate: "does this question need recursion? Duplicate!" Never mind that the objective for the "duplicate" and the original deal with entirely separate issues and seek entirely different results. For the love of all that is holy, give these guys a break,

Comment: @AaronBrandhagen I see where you're coming from (which is why I didn't close the question as dupe), but you have to admit that this is just a trivial combination of the two questions *"How do I invert a dict?"* and *"How do I print a comma-separated list of values?"*. I've added a relevant dupe.

Comment: Aran. I truly appreciate your disposition in response. The learning curve in programming is unparalleled. There's nothing that even compares. Patterns don't exist. It's exactly what it's called: code. The knowledge gap between an adept coder and a beginner (especially self-taught) is literally incomprehensible. The simplest, most rudimentary piece of code to you is hundreds/thousands of hours of work removed from a beginner to even have a decent understanding of it. Programming is a galactic web of interrelated abstraction. The difficulty grows exponentially as more layers are added. .....

Comment: So, trivial questions to you is to the beginner yet another piece of the jigsaw - cramming yet another pattern-less concept/paradigm into memory and connecting them to the rest of material learned  while constantly running into mindless, infuriating contradictions that need to be kept to memory, too. Let me know if I make any sense. I hate having conversations like these via text, so much can get lost, misunderstood.

Comment: The point (sorry, I'm VERY passionate about this subject): the smallest of differences in code are most of the time hundreds of conditions/rules removed from each other.  And those conditions and rules have cascading effect on a lot more than the single issue at hand. Patterns are learned eventually, but only after the curve is surpassed. That soul-crushing, beast of a curve. By that point? You know what you know with out any sort of map or patterns to frame what you know. So, once the basics become basic to you, it's impossible to know how a beginner is processing their own web of learning.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can approach this problem.

**Efficient: collections.defaultdict(list)**

Construct a new dictionary with keys and values inverted. Importantly, you can have duplicate values, so we use a list to hold these. The Pythonic approach is to use `collections.defaultdict`.

For very large dictionaries, this may have a large memory overhead.

```
example = {'a': 10, 'b': 12, 'c': 10, 'd': 12}

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in example.items():
    d[v].append(k)

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, ' '.join(v))

10 a c
12 b d
```

**Manual: loop of list comprehensions**

This way is computationally inefficient, but requires less memory overhead:

```
for value in set(example.values()):
    print(value, ' '.join([k for k, v in example.items() if v == value]))

10 a c
12 b d
```

Comment: at least someone who uses `' '.join([])`  (listcomp in join)

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you're after?

```
for i in set(example.values()):
    print (i, [list(example.keys())[j] for j in range(len(example)) if list(example.values())[j]==i])
```